# Why is my test double not expecting the command I allowed?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

I have some code which makes shellout calls to the Linux OS, which will run distro-specific commands.  I'm trying to ensure the tests can be run on any system, so am using a test double for the `Mixlib::ShellOut` call.  Here's a simplified version that replicates my issue:

```
require 'mixlib/shellout'
class SelinuxCommand
  def run
    runner = Mixlib::ShellOut.new('getenforce')
    runner.run_command
  end
end
```

My test stubs `Mixlib:ShellOut.new` returning a test double, and then says that `:run_command` should return the string `'Enforcing'`:

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'selinuxcommand'
describe SelinuxCommand do
  it 'gets the Selinux enforcing level' do
    command = SelinuxCommand.new
    Mixlib::ShellOut.stub(:new).and_return(double)
    allow(double).to receive(:run_command).and_return('Enforcing')
    expect command.run.to eql 'Enforcing'
  end
end
```

However, when I run the test I see:

```
$ rspec -fd selinuxcommand_spec.rb

SelinuxCommand   gets the Selinux enforcing level (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) SelinuxCommand gets the Selinux enforcing level
     Failure/Error: expect command.run.to eql 'Enforcing'
       Double received unexpected message :run_command with (no args)
     # ./selinuxcommand.rb:5:in `run'
     # ./selinuxcommand_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00197 seconds 1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./selinuxcommand_spec.rb:5 # SelinuxCommand gets the Selinux enforcing level
```

I don't understand why the double doesn't expect `:run_command` when I explicitly set it up to expect that. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just because every time you call `double` you get a different object, so the object allowed to receive the `run_command` method is not the same object returned by the stubbed `new`. You can fix it like this:

```
it 'Gets the Selinux enforcing level' do
  runner = double
  Mixlib::ShellOut.stub(:new).and_return(runner)

  expect(runner).to receive(:run_command).and_return('Enforcing')
  expect(subject.run).to eq('Enforcing')
end
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. I was forgetting that double is a method that returns a new double, and not just the same instance. +1 also for reminding me to use `subject` rather than instantiate a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't check now but it seems to me that you need stub `:initialize` method - not `:new`.

Try this variant:

```
Mixlib::ShellOut.stub(:initialize).and_return(double)
```

Comment: Stubbing the explicit constructor has two effects: (1) warning: removing `initialize' may cause serious problems and (2) Failures: Mixlib tries to call getenforce, which doesn't exist, and thus gives a  no such file or directory error.  This tells us that even though :new is an alias for :initialize, the stub only seems to take effect for the method explicitly called.